# ASP.NET Web Api. DependencyResolver (Autofac) перестает работать спустя некоторое время после deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, iis, inversion-of-control, autofac

Здравствуйте. 
Есть ASP.NET Web Api 2 приложение с несколькими контроллерами. В качестве IoC использую Autofac. Конфигурирую классическим способом - В Global.asax в методе Application_Start() вызываю конфигурирование Autofac, где регистрирую типы и привязываю Autofac к web.api:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(configuratedContainer);
```

Локально все работает, на сервере сразу после deploy (Win2012R2 IIS8) тоже. Но, спустя какое-то время (около 1-2 часов) простоя, на сервере работать перестает. При обращении к любому контроллеру ругается на отсутствие конструктора без параметров, как будто никакой регистрации DependencyResolver нет

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'MyTestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

Подозреваю, что IIS "впадает в спячку" освобождая ресурсы, если долго нет запросов. И когда наконец приходит запрос, он как-то не так (не перезапуская app) из нее выходит. Но это только теория.

iisreset не помогает, а повторый deploy помогает (на время)

Что это может быть?

Спасибо.

Comment: а никакие другие сообщения об ошибках не валятся, кроме той что указана?

Comment: ещё бы stack trace увидеть

Comment: Покажите конструкторы контроллеров.Вы в нем передаете DataContext?